# CaptureStackBackTrace remote process

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I need to get the stack trace of a remote process. I cannot use StackWalk64 because it is only single threaded. However CaptureStackBackTrace only returns the stack trace of the current process... Also StackWalk64 requires debug info / symobls

Comment: StackWalk64 doesn't require debug info / symbols. Also why is it a problem that it is single threaded?

Comment: Oh i thought it did. It is a problem since what I am doing requires more than 1 thread?!

Comment: So you want to get stack traces of multiple threads at the same time?

Comment: yes that is what i want to do. @ssbssa

Comment: I really would like to know what kind of software you are writing that requires this. Also, why not just synchronize all calls of StackWalk64 like the documentation suggests?